# (Simple) What is an "iteration" in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, mars-simulator

We have a fairly easy assignment due tomorrow on Assembly (introductory, never used it before) and we get this code:

```
    .text
main:
    li  $s0,0x30
loop:
    move    $a0,$s0     # copy from s0 to a0

    li  $v0,11      # syscall with v0 = 11 will print out
    syscall         # one byte from a0 to the Run I/O window

    addi    $s0,$s0,3   # what happens if the constant is changed?
                # A: It jumps over characters

    li  $t0,0x5d
    bne $s0,$t0,loop
    nop

stop:   j   stop        # l
    nop         # delay slot filler (just in case)oop forever here
```

And we get this question to answer:

> Consider the large loop in the the program – from the label 'loop' to
>   the branch 'bne loop'. How many iterations are executed in this loop?

This confuses me. Iterations *in* the loop? I always thought one iteration meant on "lap" of the entire loop (i.e. if the loop runs 5 times, it has performed 5 iterations).

Does "iteration" mean something else in Assembly?
If it just means "how many lines of code are executed in the loop?" then the answer is 5, but I'm fairly confused.

Comment: You are overthinking this. It's just what you said by "laps", nothing special.

Comment: @Jester Alright, thanks